# Understanding closures - capturing values

Tags: swift, closures

In The Swift Programming Language doc, Closures, "Capturing Values" has the following example:

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    var runningTotal = 0
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}
```

I follow the description except for why runningTotal is only initialized to 0 the first time makeIncrementer is called. The doc shows the following:

```
let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 10
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 20
incrementByTen()
// returns a value of 30
```

Why isn't runningTotal reset to 0 every time incrementByTen is called?

Comment: Because it was captured. That is the point of the example! That is what a closure _is_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as good a lesson about scope as it is capturing. In the original example, `runningTotal` is outside of the scope of `incrementer()` and `incrementer()` has captured this value. If you place `runningTotal` inside `incrementer()`, changing its scope, the output will reset to `0` every time it's called because `runningTotal` is now locally scoped and its value will not persist outside of the function—nothing is captured here.

```
func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        var runningTotal = 0 // local
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}

let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen() // 10
incrementByTen() // 10
incrementByTen() // 10
```

Assume `runningTotal` was a global variable, declared outside of everything. It should be clear now why the value isn't reset each time the function is called. But to `incrementer()`, this scope is no different than in the original example. In both cases, `runningTotal` is a variable outside of the scope of the function that it captured.

```
var runningTotal = 0 // global

func makeIncrementer(forIncrement amount: Int) -> () -> Int {
    func incrementer() -> Int {
        runningTotal += amount
        return runningTotal
    }
    return incrementer
}

let incrementByTen = makeIncrementer(forIncrement: 10)
incrementByTen() // 10
incrementByTen() // 20
incrementByTen() // 30
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Very helpful in understanding how this all goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the return value:

`makeIncrementer` returns `incrementer`, the inner function, `amount` and `runningTotal` are captured, and `runningTotal` is set once.